Why Safearea color remains darker than Scaffold color even though it´s the same color in flutter?
I have noticed a color shade difference between the Scaffold color and the SafeArea color even though I am applying the same colors to it.
It's not working if I'm applying the following:
Color color=const Color(0xE8024585);

but it´s working with the following
Color color=Colors.blue;

Here´s the full code:
class PractiseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PractiseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color=const Color(0xE8024585);
    //Color color=Colors.blue;// this is showing same color
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: color,
        body: Container(
          color: color,
          child: Center(child: Text('Safearea is darker than scaffod',style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          ),),),
        ),
      ),),
    );
  }
}



Apologies, I overlooked something. I've decided to update my answer again. But this time, I ensure that it works fine now (with thorough testing). You have to choose which approach you prefer to use.

May I know what happened in your system bar now? What is your findings with it?

I hope you won't forget to respond to a specific answer you consider useful to help other future readers. Thanks!

You're having a conflict with the different rendering of background color between the SafeArea's child and the system bar on the device because you set the Container as your parent widget, then you wrapped SafeArea with the parent widget Container (you did this just to prevent conflict between your app content and the system bar, particularly when there's a device notch, etc.).
I've noticed that before by doing some set of tests and trial and error. I found that it is because of having a color (background color) from the parent widget Container, then the effect of changing the color (or having a darker color) even if the specified color is the same as the child of the SafeArea widget with the parent widget background color, and it is due to the default behavior of SafeArea to produce or ensure a visible gap between the app content (i.e., its child) and the device's system bar (most probably because of trying to maintain the contrast ratio of the system bar background over the content inside it, such as labels and icons). It is likely to maintain the UI aesthetic of Android OS UI over the control of Flutter UI (as its default).
Interestingly, here's how I resolved that case:
Replace your code snippet,
class PractiseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PractiseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color=const Color(0xE8024585);
    //Color color=Colors.blue;// this is showing same color
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: color,
        body: Container(
          color: color,
          child: Center(child: Text('Safearea is darker than scaffod',style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          ),),),
        ),
      ),),
    );
  }
}

with,
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PractiseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PractiseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color = const Color(0xE8024585);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: color,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: color,
        toolbarHeight:
            0, // to resolve the issue of having distinct color with the system bar, or if you want to use an `AppBar`,
               // you can remove the toolbarHeight property or replace the 0 with `kToolbarHeight` value to have a default toolbarHeight
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: color,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Safearea is darker than scaffod',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

UPDATE:
To achieve the same output using your current code snippet (having the Container widget as your parent widget), here's how:
Use SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PractiseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PractiseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color = const Color(0xE8024585);

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: color,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, // Status bar icons (for iOS)
        statusBarIconBrightness:
            Brightness.dark, // Status bar icons (for Android)
      ),
    );

    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: color,
          body: Container(
            color: color,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Safearea is darker than scaffod',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

It works as well if you omit the parent widget Container (since its color will be overridden by the SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle's statusBarColor properties) and then wrapping the Scaffold with the SafeArea widget will be unnecessary (of course, to achieve your desired outcomes, which is to avoid having a distinct background color between the system bar and app content), since Scaffold itself uses a default behavior in respect of the device's system bar:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PractiseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PractiseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color = const Color(0xE8024585);

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: color,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, // Status bar icons (for iOS)
        statusBarIconBrightness:
            Brightness.dark, // Status bar icons (for Android)
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: color,
      body: Container(
        color: color,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Safearea is darker than scaffod',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This will be the output from the three provided code snippets:

Apologies, technically speaking, the text presented on the output image above was supposed to be SafeArea has now the same color as Scaffold.
In summary, I've provided different approaches you can use and clarify or emphasized something for you to recognize which widget causes the conflict with the rendering of color-distinct behavior between the system bar and the app's content even though the background color properties are the same.
Note: Don't mind the padding-like from the upper-left corner; it's due to my device's front camera being placed there.
I hope it helps!

will check as soon as i get on work

Well then, I have two options offered for you. Hope you'll like it.

But i noticed your code..u have skipped safearea...its needed dear..want to solve wih the use of safearea.. without safearea its simple.

Fortunately, before you mentioned it, I've already provided another code snippet for you. You can see it now. I hope it helps! And please, I advise you to try my provided code snippets first and have to also notice the comments there. Thanks!

The alpha value (E8 = 91% opacity) results in semi-transparency, causing layers to blend differently.
Solution:
Set the color to fully opaque (alpha = 0xFF):

Color color = const Color(0xFF024585); 
/// Full opacity This ensures consistent 
/// colors across Scaffold and SafeArea.



This issue is because of the opacity component in the color you're using Color(0xE8024585). when you want to use a color with hexadecimal value the first 2 digits are the alpha channel which is for the opacity of the color.
Colors.blue is a predefined color that its alpa is 0xFF. by changing your alpha part to 0xFF your issue is going to be solve.because using 0xFF for the alpha side means that you want a fully opaque color.
FF ==> 100% of opacity.
class PractiseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PractiseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Make the color fully opaque by setting the alpha to 0xFF
    Color color = const Color(0xFF024585);

    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: color,
          body: Container(
            color: color,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'SafeArea is darker than Scaffold',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Happy coding...
